# can't download extensions via typo3 extension manager

Tags: php, macos, apache, xampp, typo3

i would like to know what causes the error:

```
    Could not access remote resource https://repositories.typo3.org/mirrors.xml.gz.
```

by trying to download a extension in extension manager.

All configuration:

```
[SYS][curlUse] = 1
```

Seems to depend on my system because version 6.2 and 7.6.4 having same error. I am using Xampp on mac os. Their server is not down because i can call https://repositories.typo3.org/mirrors.xml.gz with browser.
Anyone knows how to solve that?

Comment: Try it first with curl from the command line. If that works then try to login as the web server user: su www-data (on Debian) and try the same curl command as web server user. Then paste your attempts here.

Comment: We are enforcing HTTPS on https://repositories.typo3.org since a few weeks. Further, we are using a SSL certificate signed by a CA that isn't in the trust store of oldish systems ([announcement](https://twitter.com/TYPO3server/status/704673020556787713)). Make sure that you can connect via PHP/curl as described [here](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the line 
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` directly after 
`$ch = curl_init();` in curl.php and adding same line next to the other `curl_setopt( ... )` in GeneralUtility.php solved this issue for typo3 7.6.4. thanks for your hints. Able to add extensions now.

Comment: wanna mark this answer as solution? that would be great!